# How can I horizontally align rows in fancyhdr?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, header-footer, fancyhdr

How can I left-align the [multiple-row] text in the right portion of my header using fancyhdr?  I have something like this

```
\rhead{row 1\\row 2\\row 3}
```

where the rows aren't the same length, and I wish for them to be aligned on the left.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use `\parbox` in the argument of `\rhead`. For example:

```
\rhead{\parbox{5cm}{row 1\\row 2\\row 3}}
```

If you would like to align the widest row to the right margin, you could use `\settowidth` together with a length macro and use it for the parbox width. Or have a look at the [eqparbox](http://ctan.org/pkg/eqparbox) package for auto-sizing parboxes in general.

Comment: @Kristen: Consider not only to accept, but also to upvote Stefans answer. ;-)